# How can I trigger a model to give new data when a save occurs

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to figure out a way to do the following:
when my app opens it will load a grid view of data by subscribing to my data layer's observable. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can do some sort of data mutation to that grid view, such as hiding a grid item when a user clicks the hid button, or sort the items.. then having the data layer send the updated data to anything listing. My goal is I want any class to be able to make this manipulation and then have that new data update propagate to all the `ConnectableObservers`.

So ideally I'd be able to just call some use case in my domain layer, and have that handle saving the data to my data layer then it would call all of the listeners with my new updated data.

The problem I'm running into is that I cannot seem to think of a way to call onNext of my data layers observable without resubscribing.

Here's a pseudo code explanation of what I want in my domain layer:

```
gridRepository.hidElement(someId).onCompleteDo({action -> gridRepository.getGridData()})
```

Where `gridRepository` is just an interface to my data layer, and `hideElement()` should return an Observable.

This then should trigger the on next in my presentation layers subscriber, so my grid view updates with the newly modified data.

My underlying goal in this is to pull away this logic from some sort of event bus implementation in my presentation layer and have this logic in my domain, because I can invasion some of these data states effecting other layers than just the presentation, so it would be useful to have a central dispatch location for these events.

**Side Note:**
I built my app off of this projects structure, because I think it has an elegance to it, but it does not solve everything the way I'd like it to. : https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

Any help with this or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided upon solving this with a publish subject that's used as an event bus. It's injected into multiple classes.

```
return bookRepository.getLibrary()
        .repeatWhen(e -> eventBus.toObservable()
                .filter(event -> event.equals(LIBRARY_CHANGED)));
```

my event bus is just a publish subject with a wrapper class:

```
public class EventBus {

    private final PublishSubject<Object> _bus = PublishSubject.create();

    public void post(Object event) {
        _bus.onNext(event);
    }

    public Observable<Object> toObservable() {
        return _bus;
    }
}
```

so then on any event that should update my library I do this:

```
repository.searchLibrary(params.searchTerm)
    .doOnComplete(() -> eventBus.post(LIBRARY_CHANGED));
```

this will trigger my library to get called again.

LIBRARY_CHANGED is just an Enum element.